Using results from polyline.decode() with folium.polyline
data = {'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'route': [
            '[(42.3581, -71.0636), (42.82995815, -74.78991444)]',
            '[(43.17929819, -78.56603306),(43.40320216, -82.37774519)]',
            '[(43.49975489, -86.20965845), (43.46811941, -90.04569087)]'
        ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

route_map = folium.Map(
    location=[42.3581, -71.0636]
)

for r in df['route']:
    folium.PolyLine(locations=r, weight=3).add_to(route_map)

display(route_map)

I've downloaded a bunch of encoded polylines and decoded them with polyline 2.0.2. This gives me a dataframe column with strings that include a bunch of lat/lon pairs enclosed in parentheses and separated by commas. I then try to feed that into folium.Polyline through a loop and I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[' If I copy and paste the string into a new variable, it works fine. I know my problem here is that it's in string format, I just cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to feed that data into folium in something that isn't a string.
(fwiw, I've also tried this without looping and just putting it in as a series and got the same result.)
